# What's the exact meaning of 'Temprist'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, vocabulary, slang

I look for a word that describes a **person who loves music, food, jokes, metaphorically getting high.** I mean a person whose **MOOD or Temper** is usually good and cheerful. And it's better to be a slangy/informal word.

I know that there is a Youtuber called "a temprist"; does this name refer to the meaning I'm looking for?
Thanks!

Comment: "Exact meaning" is not a recognized concept.

Comment: The YouTube contributor  isn't "a temprist"; their name is Temprist.

Answer (score 1):

There's the term **bon viveur**, but it's not in a slang register:

> - *Bon viveur* is an English pseudo-French expression denoting someone who enjoys the good things in life, especially food and drink. Bon
>   vivant is the more authentic French term.

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_viveur)]

> - *bon vivant* [noun] (also *bon viveur*) (from French): ​a person who enjoys going out with friends and eating good food, drinking good
>   wine, etc.

[[OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bon-vivant)]

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bon-vivant) specifically mentions liking going to restaurants and parties.

A comment on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JH37ep7kj8k):

> - an Epicurean with a motto: eat, drink and be merry

Thus **Epicurean** (or **epicure**) is a formal alternative:

> *epicure*: [one who is] fond of or adapted to luxury or indulgence in sensual pleasures; having luxurious tastes or habits, especially in
> eating and drinking.

[[ODE; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=epicure&sca_esv=14fbc76bdf925f77&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=ct7QZfWZJryihbIPtPm-6A0&ved=0ahUKEwj1mqKy5bKEAxU8UUEAHbS8D90Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=epicure&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiB2VwaWN1cmUyFRAAGIAEGIoFGEMYsQMYgwEYRhj5ATIIEAAYgAQYsQMyChAAGIAEGIoFGEMyBRAAGIAEMgoQABiABBiKBRhDMg4QLhiABBjHARivARiOBTILEAAYgAQYsQMYgwEyDhAuGIAEGMcBGK8BGI4FMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyLxAAGIAEGIoFGEMYsQMYgwEYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPkBGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEDSO0GUOwEWOwEcAF4AZABAJgBcKABcKoBAzAuMbgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAg0QABiABBiKBRhDGLADwgIOEAAY5AIY1gQYsAPYAQHCAhMQLhiABBiKBRhDGMgDGLAD2AECwgIvEAAYgAQYigUYQxixAxiDARhGGPkBGJcFGIwFGN0EGEYY-QEY9AMY9QMY9gPYAQOIBgGQBhG6BgYIARABGAm6BgYIAhABGAi6BgYIAxABGBM&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

.............

There are few hits on the internet for "a temprist", and they are mainly attributive usages; the proper noun only seems established.

Answer (score 1):

An informal word to describe someone who takes pleasure in things and whose mood is usually cheerful could be

> **upbeat**
> cheerful, optimistic – [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upbeat)
> full of hope and happiness – [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upbeat)

A more formal word could be

> **convivial**
> relating to, occupied with, or fond of feasting, drinking, and good company – [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convivial)
> friendly and making you feel happy and welcome – [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convivial?q=+convivial)